# Argument passing to using popen3 (spawn)?

Tags: ruby, windows

I am trying to write a gem that interacts with the Android ADB command. I am having trouble trying to understand how arguments are passed to sub-processes.

I am using the POpen4 gem, which is just a wrapper around the platforms specific open3/open4 modules. On OSX I run the following and I get back the desired output:

```
>> require 'POpen4'
=> true
>> POpen4::popen4("/Library/android-sdk-mac_x86/platform-tools/adb shell pm list packages -f") do |pout, perr, pin|
?> pout.each { |line| puts line.to_s.strip }
>> end
package:/system/app/Fallback.apk=com.android.fallback
package:/system/app/SoundRecorder.apk=com.android.soundrecorder
..<snip>..
package:/system/app/VpnServices.apk=com.android.server.vpn
=> #<Process::Status: pid=13833,exited(0)>
```

When I run the same on Win32 I get:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'POpen4'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> POpen4::popen4("C:\\Android\\android-sdk-windows\\platform-tools\\adb.exe shell pm list packages -f")
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe shell pm list packages -f
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open3.rb:202:in `spawn'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open3.rb:202:in `popen_run'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open3.rb:90:in `popen3'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/win32-open3-19-0.0.1/lib/win32/open3.rb:5:in `popen4'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/POpen4-0.1.4/lib/popen4.rb:48:in `popen4'
        from (irb):2
        from C:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

If I monitor what Ruby is doing using procexp I can see that it is treating the whole argument to `popen4` as the command to run:

```
ruby.exe    5800    QueryDirectory  C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe shell pm list packages -f.exe NO SUCH FILE
ruby.exe    5800    QueryOpen   C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe shell pm list packages -f.exe FAST IO DISALLOWED  
ruby.exe    5800    CreateFile  C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe shell pm list packages -f.exe NAME NOT FOUND
ruby.exe    5800    QueryDirectory  C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe shell pm list packages -f.com NO SUCH FILE
ruby.exe    5800    QueryOpen   C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe shell pm list packages -f.com FAST IO DISALLOWED  
ruby.exe    5800    CreateFile  C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe shell pm list packages -f.com NAME NOT FOUND
ruby.exe    5800    QueryDirectory  C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe shell pm list packages -f.cmd NO SUCH FILE
ruby.exe    5800    QueryOpen   C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe shell pm list packages -f.cmd FAST IO DISALLOWED  
ruby.exe    5800    CreateFile  C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe shell pm list packages -f.cmd NAME NOT FOUND
ruby.exe    5800    QueryDirectory  C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe shell pm list packages -f.bat NO SUCH FILE
ruby.exe    5800    QueryOpen   C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe shell pm list packages -f.bat FAST IO DISALLOWED  
ruby.exe    5800    CreateFile  C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe shell pm list packages -f.bat NAME NOT FOUND
ruby.exe    5800    CreateFile  C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe shell pm list packages -f NAME NOT FOUND
ruby.exe    5800    CreateFile  C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe shell pm list packages -f NAME NOT FOUND
```

Although the `popen3` docs say that this should be treated as command line and arguments:

```
The parameters +cmd…+ is passed to Process.spawn. So a commandline string and list of argument strings can be accepted as follows.

  Open3.popen3("echo a") {|i, o, e, t| ... }
  Open3.popen3("echo", "a") {|i, o, e, t| ... }
  Open3.popen3(["echo", "argv0"], "a") {|i, o, e, t| ... }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: This works fine for me using both `IO.open` and `Open3.popen3` on Win32. E.g. `Open3.popen3("nslookup stackoverflow.com") { |i,o,e,t| puts o.read }` behaves as expected. On the other hand, I was not able to get popen4 to install properly for 1.9 on Win32 due to some strange missing dependency issue. Are you sure this is not a problem with popen4 specifically on Win32?

Comment: Thanks for trying, I will see if I have problems using Open3.popen3. POpen4 needs win32-open3 to work, that module is currently broken on ruby 1.9, there is a github fork at http://github.com/matschaffer/win32-open3-19 that works with ruby 1.9